# Fetch first non-zero value in previous rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, series

Following is what my dataframe looks like. `Expected_Output` is my desired column:

```
   Group  Signal  Ready  Value  Expected_Output
0      1       0      0      3              NaN
1      1       0      1     72              NaN
2      1       0      0      0              NaN
3      1       4      0      0             72.0
4      1       4      0      0             72.0
5      1       4      0      0             72.0
6      2       0      0      0              NaN
7      2       7      0      0              NaN
8      2       7      0      0              NaN
9      2       7      0      0              NaN
```

If `Signal > 1`, then I am trying to fetch the most recent non-zero `Value` in the previous rows within the `Group` where `Ready = 1`. So in row 3, `Signal = 4`, so I want to fetch the most recent non-zero `Value of 72` from row 1 where `Ready = 1`.

Once I can fetch the value, I can do `df.groupby(['Group','Signal']).Value.transform('first')` as Signals appear repeatedly like 444 but not sure how to fetch `Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `groupby` + `ffill` with Boolean assign

```
df['Help']=df.Value.where(df.Ready==1).replace(0,np.nan)

df['New']=df.groupby('Group').Help.ffill()[df.Signal>1]
df
Out[1006]: 
   Group  Signal  Ready  Value  Expected_Output  Help   New
0      1       0      0      3              NaN   3.0   NaN
1      1       0      1     72              NaN  72.0   NaN
2      1       0      0      0              NaN   NaN   NaN
3      1       4      0      0             72.0   NaN  72.0
4      1       4      0      0             72.0   NaN  72.0
5      1       4      0      0             72.0   NaN  72.0
6      2       0      0      0              NaN   NaN   NaN
7      2       7      0      0              NaN   NaN   NaN
8      2       7      0      0              NaN   NaN   NaN
9      2       7      0      0              NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: @jpp added :-) .

Answer (score 2):

Create a series via `GroupBy` + `ffill`, then mask the resultant series:

```
s = df.assign(Value_mask=df['Value'].where(df['Ready'].eq(1)))\
      .groupby('Group')['Value_mask'].ffill()

df['Value'] = s.where(df['Signal'].gt(1))

   Group  Signal  Ready  Value
0      1       0      0    NaN
1      1       0      1    NaN
2      1       0      0    NaN
3      1       4      0   72.0
4      1       4      0   72.0
5      1       4      0   72.0
6      2       0      0    NaN
7      2       7      0    NaN
8      2       7      0    NaN
9      2       7      0    NaN
```